# Can I ignore a specific rule when using phpdocs?

Tags: documentation, phpdoc

Afternoon all,
I am receiving a buttload of

```
error   0   No summary was found for this file
```

when spitting out phpdocs on quite a large project. My documenting is absolutely fine but no matter what I do I can not get rid of this error and would really like to have a clean error log. I have read in other SO posts that this is a throwback from phpdocs 1.x days and I understand why it is occuring.

My question is, like excluding a directory can I also exclude specific rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question after a conversation with one of the phpdocumentor devs.

At the moment, no. It is a feature that was requested some time ago and has become more popular recently and thus has been scheduled for the next development sprint.

I will come back and update this question once/if its implemented.